# Matlab Declare Array

Tags: matlab

I want to declare `array` of type `integer`s named sequence.

After a simulation sequence it will look like `[1,3,4,59.........n elements]`. I do not know the value of `n` as it is a `random integer`.

How can I declare sequence as an `array` of type `int`? I did like `sequence= [1,1]` but this did not work out as sometimes only 1 element and then it has 2 instead of 1 element.

Comment: Where are the values of the array coming from? That will make a difference in what functions you can use.

Comment: Use `foo=typecast (foo,'int16')` to convert data type of `foo` from `double` _(default)_ to `int16` type. Alternatively, declare `foo` as following: `foo=int16 ([])`. 
P.S. : You can choose from a variety of [data types.](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/numeric-types.html)

Answer (score 2):

In cases where you cannot preallocate the array (when you don't know the size of the array in advance), you can use the following method:

```
sequence = [];
sequence(end+1) = 1;
sequence(end+1) = 3;
sequence(end+1) = 4;
...
```

Think of this method as treating `sequence` as a C++ `std::vector` and `sequence(end+1) = 1` is equivalent to `sequence.push_back(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

The standard format for declaring an array is:

```
foo = [];
```

and you can set any element of the array, at any time, and Matlab will resize automatically. For example:

```
foo = [];
foo(4) = 1
```

yields

```
foo = [ 0 0 0 1]
```

If you don't know how many elements your array needs to hold, you can do as Jacob suggests and simply resize the array every time. However, if this causes bottlenecks in your code (which you can find by using the profile tool in Matlab), you may want to resize less often, and use a placeholder value for the as-yet-unused elements.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [`linspace( from, to, numberOfElements )`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/linspace.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var=[ val1 val2 val3....valn]
for i=1:numel(var)
result=var(i)
end
```